# XCode 12.1 Autocomplete and TextHighliting Bugs?

Tags: xcode, macos, ide

Has this issue been happening to anyone else?

I haven't changed or updated anything within my configuration files but XCode suddenly just doesn't autocomplete as it did last week or auto-highlight Type Names like `UITextViewDelegate`.

I'm also on BigSur 11.0.1

I guess that could also be part of the issue?

[image]

For Reference, this is what one of my projects looked like last week:
(Normal)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Found the Solution:

My App/Project name contained a `\`backslash.  So something about that messed up the program functions.

I just removed all the "special characters" from project files and it resolved the issues.

---

Anyone know of a way to use `\` in just app display names?